# How to escape unicode string for regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, escaping

I need to build an re pattern based on the unicode string (e.g. I have "word", and I need something like ^"word"| "word"). However the "word" can contain special re characters. To match the "word" as it is, I need to escape special re characters in unicode string. The basic re.escape() function does the job for ascii strings. How can I do this for unicode?

Comment: Could you give a [mcve], rather than a description?

Comment: `re.escape()` does work on Unicode strings. Can you give an example where it's not giving the correct result?

Comment: In python 2.7, the escape function is implemented in this way:
`
_alphanum = frozenset(
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")

def escape(pattern):
    "Escape all non-alphanumeric characters in pattern."
    s = list(pattern)
    alphanum = _alphanum
    for i, c in enumerate(pattern):
        if c not in alphanum:
            if c == "\000":
                s[i] = "\\000"
            else:
                s[i] = "\\" + c
    return pattern[:0].join(s)
`

Comment: OK, I agree it inserts many backslashes that are unnecessary. But they don't harm the correctness of the regex either, do they?

Comment: Thanks, re.escape() really works, I did not realize that. I just forgot the brackets after the '|'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`re.escape()` inserts a backslash before every character that's not an ASCII alphanumeric. This may in fact lead to a multitude of unnecessary backslashes to be inserted, however, Python ignores backslashes that don't start a recognized escape sequence, so there is no big harm done (except possibly some performance penalty).

But if you want to build a stricter `escape()`, you can:

```
def escape(s):
    return re.sub(r"[(){}\[\].*?|^$\\+-]", r"\\\g<0>", s)
```

which only touches the actual regex metacharacters. I sure hope I didn't miss any :)